# Create new wallets on the Blockchain

Tags: bitcoin, blockchain

I am new to bitcoin and blockchain , I want to build a digital currency exchange
But don't want to interface to an external site(Polonix  for example).

I want, as a first step, to create wallets for all kinds of coins

Does "Blockchain" only work with Bitcoin?
Because I don't see an option to send "currency type" when creating a new wallet
https://blockchain.info/api

Please tell me what service or Api I'm supposed to interface with

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bitcoin and Blockchain are different things:

- Bitcoin is the first descentralized digital crypto currency. Bitcoin implements the Blockchain technology.
- Blockchain is the technology that gives you the chance to create descentralized networks.

Nowadays, there are many implementations of Blockchain: Bitcoin, Ethereum, Hyperledger Fabric, Corda, Ripple, Openchain...

If I were you, I would start reading more about Blockchain. Then, if you want to create your own cryptocurrency, I advise you to follow Ethereum's manual. https://www.ethereum.org/token. This will help you to understand better Blockchain, and also to create new wallets.

Answer (score 0):

Bitcoin is a cryptocurrency and Blockchain is a data structure or technology. 
Any cryptocurrency can be implemented using blockchain. 
Wallet is like a bank account which has account numbers and the amounts. 
I guess you want to create an user interface that shows multiple coin accounts and balances. 
you can create one wallet and connect it to the blockchain networks like bitcoin, ethereum, ripple to get the information of multiple cryptos implemented using protocols ethereum and ripple.

ethereum network uses web3 api  to connect and then eth.getBalance method to get balances of ethereum.Likewise each crypto will have a similar api and method.